# Group and Aggregate by multiple properties based on complex matching key

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java and working on a problem where I need to group and aggregate a collection based on the below Matching key, this key is a combination of properties from below mentioned classes.

```
class MyKey {    
      String planYearMonth;
      String carSeries;
      String weekNo;
      String factoryCode;
      String lineClass;
      String frameSortCode;
      String ocfClassificationCode;
      String locationIdentificationCode;
      String carGroup;
      //setters & getters
      //equals & hashcode
    }

public class OCFIdentificationInfo {    
    private String frameSortCode;   
    private String ocfClassificationCode;   
    private String locationIdentificationCode;  
    private String carGroup;    
    private String frameCode;   
    //getters 
    //setters
    //hashCode
    //equals
    //toString
}

public class DailyOCF { 
    private String planYearMonth;   
    private String carSeries;   
    private String weekNo;  
    private String day; 
    private String factoryCode; 
    private String lineClass;   
    private OCFIdentificationInfo ocfInfo   
    private int maxQty = 0; 
    private int actualQty = 0;  
    //getters 
    //setters
    //hashCode
    //equals
    //toString
}
```

The `DailyOCF` collection is populated in an `ArrayList`, sample data provided below.

```
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=00, ocfClassificationCode=MICRA   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=00], maxQty=20, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=10, ocfClassificationCode=SEDAN   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=10], maxQty=20, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=90, ocfClassificationCode=HDD navi, locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=90], maxQty=3, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=00, ocfClassificationCode=MICRA   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=00], maxQty=20, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=10, ocfClassificationCode=SEDAN   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=10], maxQty=20, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=60, ocfClassificationCode=GGRADE  , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=60], maxQty=10, actualQty=0]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=90, ocfClassificationCode=HDD navi, locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=90], maxQty=3, actualQty=0]
```

The above list needs to be grouped based on the above mentioned matching key, after the grouping the list should be like below.

```
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=90, ocfClassificationCode=HDD navi, locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=90], maxQty=3, actualQty=2]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=60, ocfClassificationCode=GGRADE  , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=60], maxQty=10, actualQty=1]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=10, ocfClassificationCode=SEDAN   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=10], maxQty=20, actualQty=2]
DailyOCF [planYearMonth=201304, carSeries=K01, weekNo=17, day=, factoryCode=BBB, lineClass=1, ocfInfo=OCFIdentificationInfo [frameSortCode=00, ocfClassificationCode=MICRA   , locationIdentificationCode=XXX, carGroup=YYY, frameCode=00], maxQty=20, actualQty=2]
```

The `actualQty` filed needs to aggregated based on the matching key.

In order to achieve this, I wrote the below java code but no luck, please have a look and let me know weather the approach is right ?

```
Map<MyKey, List<DailyOCF>> finalResult = dailyOCFList.stream()
  .collect(groupingBy(ocf -> new MyKey(ocf.planYearMonth, ocf.carSeries, ocf.weekNo, ocf.factoryCode,
      ocf.lineClass, ocf.ocfInfo.frameSortCode, ocf.ocfInfo.ocfClassificationCode,
      ocf.ocfInfo.locationIdentificationCode, ocf.ocfInfo.carGroup)));
```

This is how `DailyOCF` list is getting populated.

```
OCFIdentificationInfo info = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info.setCarGroup("YYY");
info.setFrameCode("00");
info.setFrameSortCode("00");
info.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info.setOcfClassificationCode("MICRA");

OCFIdentificationInfo info1 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info1.setCarGroup("YYY");
info1.setFrameCode("10");
info1.setFrameSortCode("10");
info1.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info1.setOcfClassificationCode("SEDAN");

OCFIdentificationInfo info2 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info2.setCarGroup("YYY");
info2.setFrameCode("90");
info2.setFrameSortCode("90");
info2.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info2.setOcfClassificationCode("HDD navi");

OCFIdentificationInfo info3 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info3.setCarGroup("YYY");
info3.setFrameCode("00");
info3.setFrameSortCode("00");
info3.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info3.setOcfClassificationCode("MICRA");

OCFIdentificationInfo info4 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info4.setCarGroup("YYY");
info4.setFrameCode("10");
info4.setFrameSortCode("10");
info4.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info4.setOcfClassificationCode("SEDAN");

OCFIdentificationInfo info5 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info5.setCarGroup("YYY");
info5.setFrameCode("60");
info5.setFrameSortCode("60");
info5.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info5.setOcfClassificationCode("GGRADE");

OCFIdentificationInfo info6 = new OCFIdentificationInfo();
info6.setCarGroup("YYY");
info6.setFrameCode("90");
info6.setFrameSortCode("90");
info6.setLocationIdentificationCode("XXX");
info6.setOcfClassificationCode("HDD navi");


DailyOCF dailyOCF = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF.setDay("");
dailyOCF.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF.setOcfInfo(info);

DailyOCF dailyOCF1 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF1.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF1.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF1.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF1.setDay("");
dailyOCF1.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF1.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF1.setOcfInfo(info1);

DailyOCF dailyOCF2 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF2.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF2.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF2.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF2.setDay("");
dailyOCF2.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF2.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF2.setOcfInfo(info2);

DailyOCF dailyOCF3 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF3.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF3.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF3.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF3.setDay("");
dailyOCF3.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF3.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF3.setOcfInfo(info3);

DailyOCF dailyOCF4 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF4.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF4.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF4.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF4.setDay("");
dailyOCF4.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF4.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF4.setOcfInfo(info4);


DailyOCF dailyOCF5 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF5.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF5.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF5.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF5.setDay("");
dailyOCF5.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF5.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF5.setOcfInfo(info5);


DailyOCF dailyOCF6 = new DailyOCF();
dailyOCF6.setPlanYearMonth("201304");
dailyOCF6.setCarSeries("K01");
dailyOCF6.setWeekNo("17");
dailyOCF6.setDay("");
dailyOCF6.setFactoryCode("BBB");
dailyOCF6.setLineClass("1");
dailyOCF6.setOcfInfo(info6);


List<DailyOCF> dailyOCFList = new ArrayList<DailyOCF>();
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF1);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF2);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF3);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF4);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF5);
dailyOCFList.add(dailyOCF6);
```

Comment: You can't just say no luck, which is very vague statement. Please explain the exact issue you are facing. I think you have to change `ocf.frameSortCode` to `ocf.ocfInfo.frameSortCode` and so on. Check this out for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @RavindraRanwala for your swift reply, corrected the reference in the question, as far as the problem is concerned .. as per my logic the grouping is not happening and not getting expected result.

Comment: @Naman I want to group by `MyKey', classificationCode is part of it.

Comment: @GangLeader It will be a great help if you could write up a small method that populates a ```List<DailyODF>```, so that others then don't have to spend time on that.

Comment: @SreeKumar Edited the question by populating the list, hope this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `Collectors.toMap` in such a case:

```
Map<MyKey, DailyOCF> finalResult = dailyOCFList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ocf -> new MyKey(ocf.planYearMonth, ocf.carSeries, ocf.weekNo, 
                        ocf.factoryCode, ocf.lineClass, ocf.ocfInfo.frameSortCode, 
                        ocf.ocfInfo.ocfClassificationCode, ocf.ocfInfo.locationIdentificationCode, 
                        ocf.ocfInfo.carGroup), Function.identity(), this::mergeDailyOCF));

List<DailyOCF> res = new ArrayList<>(finalResult.values());
```

where the underlying methods used would look like :

```
DailyOCF mergeDailyOCF(DailyOCF dailyOCF1, DailyOCF dailyOCF2) {
    return new DailyOCF(dailyOCF1.planYearMonth, dailyOCF1.carSeries, dailyOCF1.weekNo,
            dailyOCF1.factoryCode, dailyOCF1.lineClass, dailyOCF1.day,
            mergeOCFInfo(dailyOCF1.ocfInfo, dailyOCF2.ocfInfo), Math.max(dailyOCF1.maxQty, dailyOCF2.maxQty),
            Integer.sum(dailyOCF1.actualQty, dailyOCF2.actualQty)); // assign 'actualQty = 1' as default
}

OCFIdentificationInfo mergeOCFInfo(OCFIdentificationInfo info1, OCFIdentificationInfo info2) {
    return info1;
    // implement custom logic if required
    // return new OCFIdentificationInfo(info1.frameSortCode, info1.ocfClassificationCode,
    // info1.locationIdentificationCode, info1.carGroup, info1.frameCode);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but for some reason the mergeDailyOCF function is not being picked up, I am debugging and let you know the reason.

Comment: @GangLeader Ensure proper `equals` and `hashcode` for `MyKey` object for that.

Comment: implemented equals & hashCode in the key, still not getting the desired result.

Comment: @GangLeader Well with the data shared in the question (though incomplete to test the overall code) and using Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` on MyKey` I see only two `DailyOCF` as part of the result which seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

For easier readability, let us assume that you have a method to create `MyKey` from `DailyOCF`.

```
private static MyKey myKey( DailyOCF ocf ) {
    return new MyKey(ocf.planYearMonth, ocf.carSeries, ocf.weekNo, ocf.factoryCode,
              ocf.lineClass, ocf.ocfInfo.frameSortCode, ocf.ocfInfo.ocfClassificationCode,
              ocf.ocfInfo.locationIdentificationCode, ocf.ocfInfo.carGroup );
}
```

Here is what I came up with. If you want to aggregate `actualQty` or `maxQty`, the end result from the stream operation will be `Map<MyKey, Integer>`. This code will achieve it. (I have used `maxQty` in the code here, since it has some values.)

```
Map<MyKey, Integer> myKeyList = dailyOCFList.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.toMap( Function.identity(), ocf -> myKey( ocf ) ) ).entrySet().stream()
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.summingInt( e -> e.getKey().getMaxQty() ) ) );
```

If instead of summation, you simply want the grouped list of `DailyOFC`s, then you may use this:

```
Map<MyKey, List<DailyOCF>> myKeyList2 = dailyOCFList.stream()
    .collect( Collectors.toMap( Function.identity(), ocf -> myKey( ocf ) ) ).entrySet().stream()
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.mapping( e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.toList() ) ) );
```

Comment: it seems like there is an issue with the logic, both snippets are not giving expected result.

Comment: @GangLeader Oh... I was getting a ```NullPointerException``` with the data set up method you gave; so I had to write up my own. Is that the problem you are facing too? May be a little tweaking from your end on the data set up method will make it work.

Comment: Edited with the correct data, now you shoudn't face any problem.

Comment: @GangLeader Thanks. Now the NPE is not coming. Since you have anyhow got the answer, I am not pursuing this further. Hope that's fine.

Comment: no need to put any further effort, Many thanks for help.